# setSelectedIndex via delegate method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm trying to call the `setSelectedIndex` of my tabBarViewController via a delegate method in another viewController.

I've got the whole delegate part working, and the method call in my tabBarViewController correctly Logs to the console as being called.

The problem I'm having is, that it doesn't change my tabBar to the correct index. This is the method being called in my `tabBarViewController.m`

```
-(void)passNewSelectedIndex{
    NSLog(@"delegate method called"); //This correctly outputs to the logs when the delegate method is called.
    [self setSelectedIndex:1];
}
```

But it doesn't work.
Now, if I call `[self setSelectedIndex:1];` in my viewDidLoad of the tabBarViewController.m, it works, and it correctly displays the tab at index:1. But that's obviously not where I want to set it. I think I might be missing something really obvious, but I just cant figure out what.

**EDIT** Posted the code for the concerned .h's and .m's

ScoreViewController.h:

```
@protocol ScoreViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)passNewSelectedIndex;

@end

@interface CEWSoreViewController : UICollectionViewController{
    id <ScoreViewControllerDelegate> scoreDelegate;
}


@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ScoreViewControllerDelegate> scoreDelegate;

@end
```

ScoreViewController.m:

```
- (void)passNewSelectedIndex{

    CEWTabBarViewController *instanceOfTabBarCont = [[CEWTabBarViewController alloc] init];
    self.scoreDelegate = instanceOfTabBarCont;
    NSLog(@"I was called, hurray");
        [instanceOfTabBarCont passNewSelectedIndex];

}
```

TabBarViewController.h

```
#import "CEWFinalScoreViewController.h"

@interface CEWTabBarViewController : UITabBarController <UITabBarControllerDelegate, ScoreViewControllerDelegate>{
}



@end
```

tabBarViewController.m:

```
-(void)passNewSelectedIndex{
        NSLog(@"delegate method called");
    NSLog(@"self.tabBar: %@", self.tabBar);
    [self setSelectedIndex:1];
}
```

AppDelegate.m

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


CEWTabBarViewController *tabViewController = [[CEWTabBarViewController alloc] init];


self.window.rootViewController = tabViewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

Hope this makes a bit more sense now.

Comment: Are you certain that the instance of your tab bar controller on which you're calling this method is the same as the instance that is actually controlling your tab bar?  `NSLog(@"self.tabBar: %@",self.tabBar);` ???

Comment: How is the delegate being called? I.e. is it in a block? all UI changes have to happen on the main thread

Comment: For now, I am voting to close this question based on insufficient information.  This problem cannot be diagnosed (other than guesses) without more information (how is the `passNewSelectedIndex` method being called, exactly).

Comment: @nhgrif I've added some more code now from the concerned .h's and .m's

Comment: @foffer I've removed the close vote and posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is exactly as I expected:

```
- (void)passNewSelectedIndex{
    CEWTabBarViewController *instanceOfTabBarCont = [[CEWTabBarViewController alloc] init];
    self.scoreDelegate = instanceOfTabBarCont;
    NSLog(@"I was called, hurray");
    [instanceOfTabBarCont passNewSelectedIndex];
}
```

You're instantiating a new tab bar controller and calling the `passNewSelectedIndex` method on that.  The problem is, that tab bar controller isn't the one controlling the tab bar your view controllers are in.

Try this:

```
[(CEWTabBarViewController*)self.tabBarController passNewSelectedIndex];
```

Depending on your navigational setup, you may need this instead:

```
[(CEWTabBarViewController*)self.view.window.rootViewController passNewSelectedIndex];
```

We would need a LOT more of your project to figure out exactly the best way to get a reference to the right Tab Bar Controller (I'm not recommending you do this), but the point is, we have to get a reference to the already instantiated tab bar controller that is already controlling our tab bar, not simply instantiate a new one and expect it to magically control our current tab bar.

The reason it works in `viewDidLoad` of your tab bar controller is because every instance of your tab bar controller calls `viewDidLoad` on its own.  When moved into `passNewSelectedIndex`, this method is only called when someone else calls it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @nhgrif. I tried to call `[(CEWTabBarViewController*)self.tabBarController passNewSelectedIndex];` without luck. And then tried `[(CEWTabBarViewController*)self.window.rootViewController passNewSelectedIndex];`, but it wouldnt even let me call that (Property 'window' not found on CEWScoreViewController). Which led me to believe that I might have set something erroneously up in the AppDelegate. I've posted my appdelegate.m in my original post. I really appreciate your help so far by the way :)

Comment: Sorry, try `self.view.window.rootViewcontroller` in the second one @foffer

Comment: That doesn't work either. I'm starting to think that it might be the setup of my tabBarController that's something wrong with? (Obviously I'm quite new to Obejctive-C and XCODE) Would I be able to provide you with some more code to make it more clear what is happening? @nhgrif

Answer (score 0):

**selectedIndex** is a property of UITabBarController

```
[self setSelectedIndex:1];
```

This would work only if the  current controller is a subclass of UITabBarController.

For your scenario, you would have to pass the UITabBarController as a parameter

```
-(void)passNewSelectedIndex:(UITabBarController *)tabBar {
    NSLog(@"delegate method called"); 
    [tabBar setSelectedIndex:1];
}
```

If the view controller which declares your delegate method is itself a subclass of UITabBarController, then the `[self setSelectedIndex:1];`
would result in calling its own tabBar and not the one on which the delegate method is set.

Comment: No.  This answer is the exact same as another answer that just got deleted.